# Orchard CMS Create a copy of existing site on the same server

Tags: orchardcms

I have an existing Orchard CMS site.

I would simply like to create a copy of the site and I have carried out the following.

1. Copied all items in the filesystem to a new directory
2. Changed the Daatprefix label within the app_data\Sites\Default\Settings.txt to reflect the new table prefixes
3. Created duplicate DB tables with a different prefix ecc to hcc
4. Copied all the data from initial DB tables to new DB tables including identity columns.
5. Changed the baseUrl in a DB table hcc_Settings_SiteSettings2PartRecord

Set things up in IIS use the same application pool

I simply get a request timeout error when attempting the second website
HttpException (0x80004005): Request timed out

Comment: Sounds more like IIS issue, or maybe dns if this is a new domain?  Are your bindings setup correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Delete cache.dat and sites/default/mappings.bin under app_data.